# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed. IMAP Store is not connecting

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

I am not able to connect to IMAP store . It was working earlier now its throwing below error

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:474)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
```

Code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.imap.host", "outlook.office365.com"));
properties.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", String.valueOf("993")));
session = Session.getInstance(properties);
store = session.get("imap");
store.connect(username,password);
```

I checked all the links , i tried few solutions suggested but they dint work .

Debug Info.

```
  DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4ea
    DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\javamail.providers (The system cannot find the file specified)
    DEBUG: !anyLoaded
    DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers
    DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
    DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
    DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
    DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
    DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
    DEBUG: !anyLoaded
    DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
    DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\javamail.address.map (The system cannot find the file specified)
    DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
    DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
    * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [TQBBADEAUABSADAAMQAwADEAQwBBADAAMAA2ADcALgBJAE4ARABQAFIARAAwADEALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]
    A0 CAPABILITY
    * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
    A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
    IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: PLAIN
    IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH2
    DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=pavkumar0@publicisgroupe.net, password=<non-null>
    A1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
    + 
    cGF2a3VtYXIwQHB1YmxpY2lzZ3JvdXBlLm5ldABwYXZrdW1hcjBAcHVibGljaXNncm91cGUubmV0AFNyaWRoYWJ2cmsrMTM=
    A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:474)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
```

Comment: Start by fixing these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  If you're sure you're using the correct user name and password, the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) may have more information about why the server is rejecting your credentials.

Comment: i have checked the common mistakes  and it was working fine few days before now its throwing the Authentication failed , tried changing the password and with other credentials still same error.. please check the java mail debug info above

Comment: You're using a **very** old version of JavaMail, please [upgrade](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) and see if that solves your problem.  Also, change your password **immediately**, it's exposed in encoded form above.

Comment: i checked with  java mail 1.4 , 1.4.7, 1.5.0-b01 , nothing is working , i changed the password and checked with new credentials . still its throwing the same error

Comment: i even checked with latest  javax.mail-api 1.5.6 even with this its throwing authentication failed , i checked imap, pop3 connections with gmail , yahoo , outlook they all are throwing same authentication failed error .

Comment: The latest version of JavaMail is 1.6.1.  Have you tried using Thunderbird to connect to the same account using the same user name and password?  If you can’t log in to any of your accounts on any mail server anywhere, then you may have an anti-virus or firewall program that’s interfering with your connection.

Comment: yeah i have tried JavaMail 1.6.1 as well and to check  firewall program interference i tried connecting to the servers in  my home laptop still it throws same error. i tried thunderbird to connect to the same account it dint work for outlook but i was  able to connect to my gmail account using thunderbird.

Comment: If you can connect to Gmail using Thunderbird you should also be able to connect using JavaMail, although you'll need to [enable less secure apps](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmailauth).  But if your real goal is to connect to office365.com, you should figure out why Thunderbird can't connect.  Clearly the problem there has nothing to do with JavaMail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authentication failed error was coming as the Imap for the account was not enabled at firewall.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this issue in reading emails from an outlook office365 account which was upgraded recently.

I changed code to use [microsoft ews-java-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide) and issue resolved.

Example code to make connection and read emails with attachment and passed subject using [microsoft ews-java-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide):

```java
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.PropertySet;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.misc.ExchangeVersion;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.property.WellKnownFolderName;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.search.LogicalOperator;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.schema.ItemSchema;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.WebCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.FileAttachment;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.search.ItemView;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.folder.Folder;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.search.filter.SearchFilter;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExchangeEmailTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ExchangeService service = createConnection();
            readAttachmentEmail(service);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static ExchangeService createConnection() throws Exception {
        String email = "your email";
        String password= "your email password";
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(email, password);
        service.setUrl(new URI("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
        service.setCredentials(credentials);
        return service;
    }

    private static void readAttachmentEmail(ExchangeService service) throws Exception {
        // Bind to the Inbox.
        Folder inbox = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
        // set number of items you want to retrieve
        ItemView view = new ItemView(1);
        List<SearchFilter> searchFilterCollection = new ArrayList<>();
        // flag to pick only email which contains attachments
        searchFilterCollection.add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.HasAttachments, Boolean.TRUE));
        searchFilterCollection.add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject,"subject filter"));
        SearchFilter finalSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, searchFilterCollection);
        ArrayList<Item> items =  service.findItems(inbox.getId(), finalSearchFilter, view).getItems();
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(items)) {
            Item item= items.get(0);
            System.out.println("id==========" + item.getDateTimeReceived());
            System.out.println("sub==========" + item.getSubject());
            EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, item.getId(), new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Attachments));
            FileAttachment attachment = (FileAttachment) message.getAttachments().getItems().get(0);
            attachment.load(" < attachment save directory > "+attachment.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the plain password,create a app password and use it.It will work.

Steps Login to Office 365 Got MYAccount-->Security and Privacy-->Additional security verification-->Create and manage app passwords

Just use the below properties only

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.host", "outlook.office365.com");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for gmail account when i try to run the code in different device .It is because the google will not allow the gmail account to login to other device .Solution to this is you should allow access to the account using below url :

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha